# Execute postgresql query for multiple input dates

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, date

I have this postgres query:

```
select to_date('10.11.19','dd.mm.yy') as date,"licenseId",count("licenseId") as lizenseCount,round(sum("yearlyCostEurCents")::numeric/1200,2) as mrr
from "Subscription"
where "versionOf" < to_date('10.11.19','dd.mm.yy')
and not ( "cancelledAt" < to_date('10.11.19','dd.mm.yy') and  "isArchived")
group by "licenseId";
```

and i want to execute it for an array of dates `(['10.11.19','11.11.19',...]).` Is there any way to do this in postgresql?

Edit: Apparently I'm not good at asking questions...

What I meant was I have an array of dates (something like(`([date_1,date_2,...,date_n])`) and now I want to execute this query: for every date in the array.

```
select to_date(date_*,'dd.mm.yy') as date,"licenseId",count("licenseId") as lizenseCount,round(sum("yearlyCostEurCents")::numeric/1200,2) as mrr
from "Subscription"
where "versionOf" < to_date(date_*,'dd.mm.yy')
and not ( "cancelledAt" < to_date(date_*,'dd.mm.yy') and  "isArchived")
group by "licenseId";
```

Is there a way to do this in postgresql? Because at the moment I have a for loop in my code that does this, but thats of course very slow.

Comment: you can convert array to table check `unnest` function. then you can `join` / `cross apply` on that table

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: @ArjunVachhani: there is no `cross apply` in Postgres or standard SQL. It's called a lateral join there, e.g. `cross join lateral`

Comment: @bear14: I am unsure how the use of multiple dates should work. If `"versionOf" < '2019-11-10'` is true then obviously `versionof < '2019-11-11` is also true, so how exactly do you want to compare the array elements? So passing `2019-11-10` **and** `2019-11-11` in the array doesn't seem to make much sense

Answer (score 0):

If you want a range, you can use the where clause:

```
  select to_date('10.11.19','dd.mm.yy') as date,
         "licenseId",count("licenseId") as lizenseCount,
         round(sum("yearlyCostEurCents")::numeric/1200,2) as mrr
    from "Subscription"
   where "versionOf" < to_date('10.12.19','dd.mm.yy') -- > 10.12.19
     and "versionOf" > to_date('10.11.19','dd.mm.yy') -- AND < 10.11.19
     and not ( "cancelledAt" > to_date('10.11.19','dd.mm.yy') and "cancelledAt < to_date('10.12.19', 'dd.mm.yy') and  "isArchived")
group by "licenseId";
```

If you have a specific set of dates, you can use `IN` clause that get a set of elements to compare with the column value.

```
  select to_date('10.11.19','dd.mm.yy') as date,
         "licenseId",count("licenseId") as lizenseCount,
         round(sum("yearlyCostEurCents")::numeric/1200,2) as mrr
    from "Subscription"
   where "versionOf" IN (to_date('10.11.19','dd.mm.yy'), to_date('11.11.19','dd.mm.yy'), to_date('12.11.19','dd.mm.yy'))
     and not ( "cancelledAt" IN (to_date('10.11.19','dd.mm.yy'), to_date('11.11.19','dd.mm.yy'), to_date('12.11.19','dd.mm.yy')) and  "isArchived")
group by "licenseId";
```

The first select, in time complexity is more efficient than the second select.